# How to annotate function attributes?

Tags: python, python-typing

[PEP 232](https://peps.python.org/pep-0232/) defines function attributes, and [PEP 484](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/) defines annotations, but I can't find how the two should be combined.

E.g.

```
def foo(s:str):
  try:
    print (foo.cache[s])
  except Exception:
    print ('NEW')
    foo.cache[s] = 'CACHE'+s

foo.cache = dict{}
```

How can I annotate `foo.cache` inside `foo()`, before using it?

Comment: You can only annotate *names*, not expressions like `foo.cache`. If you were defining a subclass of function (and it were possible to instantiate such a class using a `def` statement) then you could do something like `class MyFunction: cache: dict`.

Comment: You can't, because function attributes are only ever added dynamically

Answer (score 1):

You can use a callable class, since Python does not support defining a function while annotating its type:

```py
import typing

class Cacheable:
    cache: dict[str, str]
    _call: typing.Callable[[str], None]
    
    def __init__(self, call: typing.Callable[[str], None]) -> None:
        self.cache = {}
        self._call = call
    
    def __call__(self, s: str) -> None:
        return self._call(s)

@Cacheable
def foo(s: str) -> None:
    try:
        print(foo.cache[s])
        # print(foo.otherattribute[s])
        # mypy -> "Cacheable" has no attribute "otherattribute"  
    except KeyError:
        print('new')
        foo.cache[s] = f'cache{s}'

# foo.someotherattribute = {}
# mypy -> "Cacheable" has no attribute "someotherattribute"

foo('a')
foo('a')
foo('b')
```